# MVC Razor Html.Partial sub model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem concerning Partial views in MVC Razor. Any help is highly appreciated, it's most likely something I've missed, but I could find nothing while searching that had the same problem replicated.

So I'm binding my view to a view model.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ContactInformation ContactInformation { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have a view with a partial to render the contact information model.

```
<div>
    @Model.Name
</div>
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_ContactInformation", Model.ContactInformation)
</div>
```

However, the "_ContactInformation" view is rendered without ContactInformation in the `name`attribute of the `<input>`s

Usually razor binds the name attribute to something like: name="ContactInformation.Address". But since it's a partial it gets rendered as name="Address".

Am I missing something or is this the intended way for it to work?

Comment: This is working as intended. Views are self contained, they are not aware of parent views/models.  If you want this to work properly you'll need to use [`@Html.EditorFor(model, template)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414(v=vs.118).aspx) instead of `@Html.Partial()`.

Comment: I think there is better way of latest MVC, but at least that should help - http://thatextramile.be/blog/2011/01/prefixing-input-elements-of-partial-views-with-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if I were to go down the partial view (which is an odd way to go for something that creates editor template output...)  I'd rather use an interface (which creates a nice stronly typed view) then create a new editor method that has a magic string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options. Option 1 - specify the prefix explicitly:

```
@Html.Partial("_ContactInformation", Model.ContactInformation, new ViewDataDictionary
{
    TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "ContactInformation" }
})
```

Options 2 is to turn partial view into an editor template for your model and than use `EditorFor` helper method, that should be able to add prefixes for you:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ContactInformation)
```